# Intel desktop board `warning:have option ROM can not be invoke`

Tags: hard-drive, boot, compact-disc, hardware-raid

I had an old computer on which I am going to install lubuntu or any lightweight Linux distribution.It was packed in box for at least 2 or 3 years and it is approximately 11 years of old.It has Intel mother board.now I had unpacked it and start using it again, but it was not booting up.thus my father unplugged CD ROM drive and one slave hard-disk.and then I am able to boot. but it takes to much time.every time when I boot up, it gives me following warning:

```
warning:have option ROM can not be invoke
```

[image: - [image of when it starts][1]]
 [image: - [image of warnings][2]]

and then it boots up.I had disabled the CD ROM from BIOS. I cant add screen-shot of that because I am new to this site(more than 2).

Comment: Message appears to be referring to a Realtek Ethernet adapter http://pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1697

Comment: @DavidMarshall what is this link you have provided?I am noob and  I Didn't find out anything on it.

Comment: It gives you the device id 8139 for the vendor id 10EC. Looks like a BIOS problem. Has the motherboard battery failed while it was stored?